# Tensorflow saver is not functioning properly

Tags: python, tensorflow

I made a saver to save my model in my testing module. Since, tensorflow is using a new saving scheme, it does not store .ckpt file directly. So instead of .ckpt file we have .data-00000-of-00001 and .index files.

My code for saving :

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
save_path = saver.save(sess, 'D:\Speech_Project\my_model\my_model_01')
```

And for restoring :

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('D:\Speech_Project\my_model\my_model_01.meta')
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
```

The error i am getting is :

```
TypeError: expected bytes, NoneType found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/BanglaCNN01/banglacnn05.py", line 318, in <module>
test_cnn(X1)
File "C:/Users/admin/PycharmProjects/BanglaCNN01/banglacnn05.py", line 243, in test_cnn
saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./'))
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1428, in restore
{self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 767, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 965, in _run
feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
target_list, options, run_metadata)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1022, in _do_call
return fn(*args)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1004, in _run_fn
status, run_metadata)
SystemError: <built-in function TF_Run> returned a result with an error set

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Please note, all codes are in the same .py file. Tensorflow version 1.0.1 for Windows CPU version. Even with

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

the error is same. Need your insights please.

Comment: Could it be that passing ./ to latest_checkpoint is finding the wrong one?

Comment: Donot think so, i am saving only one instance of the model when my training reaches 100. I donot know any other restore method.

Comment: Like, can you pass the full path, D:\Speech_Project\my_model\my_model_01 ?